# Limit the number of registrations by field

Tags: 7, rules

I am using Entityforms to take registrations for events. There is limited space and the form allows users to select which event they would prefer to attend.

Is there any way (rule, etc.) to disable or remove certain dates once the limit has been reached?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable specific dates in date popup by implementing some custom code as per shown in [jQuery UI DatePicker: Disable Specified Days](https://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days). To [work with jQuery in Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/working-with-javascript-and-jquery) you can check the [date popup alter example here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1251642).

OR you can try [Work Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/work_calendar) Module with [Date Restrictions](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_restrictions) Module (both are in dev and not suggested to use on Production unless working without any error).

Comment: These are helpful, but the form is built so that a user selects a pre-set value from a select list that is posted to the database. I need a way to count how many people select a particular value. For example: 20 seats are available for April. So only 20 people should be able to sign up for that month.

Comment: Ok, so to restrict the signup based on number of seat, you can add custom validate handler by altering form (check [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/hook_form_alter) for adding custom validate handler) and then checking form has 20 submissions or not. If yes, then restrict user saying no available seat.